# Select tag default value in case of hardcoded options mgModel

Tags: angular, angular5, jhipster, ngmodel

By selecting a value by setting `this.model.type = OPTION_NR1`, angular sets HTML attribure `ng-reflect-model` in HTML to **0**, which is default enum value and the Option1. The correct value for the HTML attribute is **OPTION_NR1**, which fills the drop-down with Option1 instead of leaving it empty.

*What current setup does*: `<select ..  ng-reflect-model="0">`
*What it should do*: `<select ..  ng-reflect-model="OPTION_NR1">`

```
<select [(ngModel)]="model.type"  required>
   <option value="OPTION_NR1" >Option1</option>
   <option value="OPTION_NR2" >Option2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you show how `OPTION_NR1` is defined in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your enum to use [TypeScript's string enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums).

If your enum looks like:

```
export const enum Type {
    'OPTION_NR1',
    'OPTION_NR2'
}
```

Change it to:

```
export const enum Type {
    OPTION_NR1 = 'OPTION_NR1',
    OPTION_NR2 = 'OPTION_NR2'
}
```

This was done in the generator in [this pull request](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/7557) and is available in versions v5.0.0-beta.1 and above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether I get you right. But it seems as if you want your model.type field to be a string rather than the 0 which represents the enum's index.

So I assume that your Enum is named "Types". Try it this way:

```
this.model.type = Types[this.model.type];
```

If this is not what you expected, please be more specific.